# How to complete this Jquery string

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to use this piece of Jquery to open a lightbox gallery on page load IF the class .w-condition-invisible is appended to the #script-test div.

This is what I've come up with but upon testing in the console it's not working...

Any ideas?

```
$( "#script-test" ).hasClass( "w-condition-invisible" ){
  $('.w-lightbox').first().trigger('tap');
});
```

Comment: `if($( "#script-test" ).hasClass( "w-condition-invisible" )){$('.w-lightbox').first().trigger('tap');}`

Comment: As @Satpal suggested, you need to use conditional statement

Answer (score 1):

Create a class to show Popup and when remove popup will hide
using this You can open lightbox(popup)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#script-test" ).addClass("showpopup");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, what i understood is in the below code, please have a look:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  if($( "#script-test" ).hasClass( "w-condition-invisible" )){
    $('.w-lightbox').first().trigger('tap');
  }
});
```

Please have a look on this.

Hope, this may be helpful to you.

Comment: Please have a look on this, this much i am able to get from your question, if this does not work, please provide your html code also, where you to do click event, then only i could be able to help in a much better way.

Answer (score 0):

Check by length

```
   $(window).load(function() {
      if($( ".w-condition-invisible" ).length){
        $('.w-lightbox').first().trigger('tap');
      }
    });
```